# PHP Put request (update ECWID e-commerce order with tracking)

Tags: php, json, xml

I am working with the Ecwid API, and now moving towards updating my order from our fulfillment site with tracking info and shipping status.

Fulfillment Operation is going to export a xml file of the order update.

I have first created the basic script to update a product and this works fine.

```
    // Post Tracking number and change Status to shipped
    // trackingNumber : ""
    // fulfillmentStatus : "SHIPPED"

$storeID = "";
$myToken = "";

$data = array("trackingNumber" => "9405503699300250719362", "fulfillmentStatus" => "SHIPPED", "orderNumber" => "7074");
$data_string = json_encode($data);


$url = "https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/".urlencode($storeID)."/orders/".$data['orderNumber']."?token=".$myToken;


$ch = curl_init($url);                                                                    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)));

$response  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I've also created the script to pull in the xml file and convert to json to 'put' the data over to the shopping cart.

```
<?php
// The file data.xml contains an XML document with a root element
// and at least an element /[root]/title.

if (file_exists('data.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');

    print_r($xml);
} else {
    exit('Failed to open data.xml.');
}

$data_string = json_encode($xml);

echo '<br> br>';
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data_string);

?>
```

Now this is where i am lost to put the two parts together so that it would loop through the xml file (json content) with multiple "orderNumber(s)" and update the trackingNumber and fulfillmentStatus of each order.

Answer (score 0):

Vitaly from Ecwid team here.

I see that you want to update orders in your Ecwid store via API from an XML file.

So the whole process is:

- get details of XML file
- parse data in it, find out the total number of orders there
- form a loop for each order in the file
- make a request to Ecwid API to update order in each loop

In your second code snippet, I see `print_r($data_string);` - what does it print to the screen?

I imagine the next steps would be:

1. Manage to correctly find order details in the XML file (order
   number, tracking number) while in the loop
2. Make each loop update specific order in the store

**For the step 1**, I suggest saving data from XML file to a convenient format for you in PHP, e.g. object or array.

For example, if it was an array, it will be something like this:

```
Array = [recordArray 1, recordArray 2, recordArray 3]

recordArray = [ orderNumber, trackingNumber ]
```

**For the step 2**: So each loop will go through an recordArray in the Array and then get the necessary orderNumber and trackingNumber for the request.

Then the request will use this data to update an order in your Ecwid store, just like you shown in the code snippet above. However the values: `9405503699300250719362` and `7074` will be dynamic and different for **each** loop.

If you have any questions, please feel free to contact me: http://developers.ecwid.com/contact

Thank you.